# Can we use server SAS 2.5" hard drives for SAN?

Tags: san

I have 2.5" SAS hard drives in a lot of servers. Now we are planning to buy a SAN and want to utilize the existing hard drives. Can we use those hard drives in SAN storage? Someone told me that server storage and SAN storage is different.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of SAN storage systems. If you decide buying an enterprise-class storage system, that vendor storage will force you to buy their drives as well.

If you buy a custom build system, you should check their specifications. Keep in mind, drives are very important part of the storage system and in highly loaded environments drives can die very often in this case reusing of old drives can add more issues to you then benefits.